# PowerShell: Start Specific Tasks/Processes on Specific Nodes

Tags: windows, powershell, loops, server

I have a process that goes out and creates Agent folders on a file share based on the amount of CPUs that were requested by the user.  For example, if the user requests two servers (This is being done in AWS) that has 2 CPUs each, my process would create 4 Agent folders on the file share i.e. Agent1, Agent2, Agent3, Agent4.

Within each Agent folder are files that have an .exe file, lets call it test.exe.  What I need to happen is have each Agent folder run based on the CPU count.  So in this example Agent1 and Agent2 would run on server1 and Agent3 and Agent4 would run on server2.

Here is my current code:

```
        $NodeArray = @('server1','server2')
        $a = 1
        $Node = 2 (Calculation done to divide the total amount of CPUs by the # of servers requested)
        
        Foreach ($server in $NodeArray) {             

         (Runs Invoke command to create PSSession then runs Invoke to map the share locally)

              $ScriptBlock = { param ($MasterNode, $ControlFile, $Node, $a)
              do {
                 $Arguments = "$ControlFile /H ${MasterNode}:4004"
                 Start-Process -FilePath "test.exe" -WorkingDirectory "C:\Test\Agent$a" -ArgumentList $Arguments
                 Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                 $a++
              } Until ($a -gt $Node)
                                
              $Node = $Node + $Node
        }
    }
```

This is working however it starts Agent1 on server 1 then on server 2, then moves to Agent2 and starts it on server 1 then on server 2 and so on all up to Agent4 then breaks the loop.

As stated previously, expected behavior should be Agent1 and Agent2 on server 1, then iterate and loop and start Agent3 and Agent4 on server 2.

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide!

EDIT:

```
$NodeArray = @('172.22.218.100', '172.22.150.140')
$NumServer = 2
$CPU = 2
$Global:CPUTotal = [int]$CPU * 2
$Node = [int]$CPUTotal / [int]$NumServer
$a = 1
write-host "A 1: $a"
write-host "Node 1: $node"
   
    Foreach ($server in $NodeArray) {

        write-host "A 2: $a"
        write-host "Node 2: $node"
        
        $ScriptBlock = {
            param ($computer, $Node, $a)

            write-host "A 3: $a"
            write-host "Node 3: $node"
            
            do {
                Write-Host server: $computer `t Max Agent: $Node `t Agent: $a
                write-host "A 4: $a"
                write-host "Node 4: $node"
                $a++
            } Until ($a -gt $Node)

            write-host "A 5: $a"
            write-host "Node 5: $node"

            }

        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $server, $a, $Node

        $a = $Node + 1

        $Node = $Node + $Node

    }
```

When I run this above code, i receive this output:

```
A 1: 1
Node 1: 2
A 2: 1
Node 2: 2
A 3: 2
Node 3: 1
server: 172.22.218.100   Max Agent: 1    Agent: 2
A 4: 2
Node 4: 1
A 5: 3
Node 5: 1
A 2: 3
Node 2: 4
A 3: 4
Node 3: 3
server: 172.22.150.140   Max Agent: 3    Agent: 4
A 4: 4
Node 4: 3
A 5: 5
Node 5: 3
```

I'm doing a write-host on `$Node` and as you can see the first and second one is equal to 2 which is correct, but the minute it gets into the `$Scriptblock` it sets it to 1.  I'm getting the same behavior for `$a` (although the number is different).  You mentioned the `$Scriptblock` is a different scope, will it not pass the value as declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue is with the scope of your $a variable.  The $a variable inside your scriptblock is not the same as the $a defined outside it so after the scriptblock runs your $a variable will still be set to 1 and your next server will again start at agent1.  You need to redefine your $a variable after each run.

```
    $NodeArray = @('server1', 'server2')
    $a = 1
    $Node = 2       # (Calculation done to divide the total amount of CPUs by the # of servers requested)
    
    Foreach ($server in $NodeArray) {
    
        #  (Runs Invoke command to create PSSession then runs Invoke to map the share locally)
    
        $ScriptBlock = {
            param($computer, $Node, $a)
            do {
                Write-Host server: $computer `t Max Agent: $Node `t Agent: $a
                $a++
            } until ($a -gt $Node)
        }
    
    
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ArgumentList $server, $Node, $a
    
        # $a is still equal to 1 here since $a in scriptblock has a different scope
    
        # set $a to next Agent
        $a = $Node + 1
    
        $Node = $Node + $Node
    }
```

```
server: server1          Max Agent: 2    Agent: 1
server: server1          Max Agent: 2    Agent: 2
server: server2          Max Agent: 4    Agent: 3
server: server2          Max Agent: 4    Agent: 4
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel,  I do see this is working however when I try to add more specifics pertaining to my code, for some reason $Node and $a are incrementing while getting into the scriptblock.  I'll add and edit above.

Comment: In your new example you have `$a` and `$Node` reversed in your Invoke-Command argument list.  Scriptblock `param ($computer, $Node, $a)` and you have `-ArgumentList $server, $a, $Node`

Comment: Ugghhh, I didnt realized it was ordered.  That did it!  Thanks for all your help.  Been beating my head against the wall for a couple days now staring at this.